# button to start transition in d3js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, button, d3.js, transition

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>




</style>
<button>transition</button>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>




var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1200)
  .attr("height", 675)


var mySquare = canvas.append("rect")
  .attr("x",60)
  .attr("y",60)
  .attr("width",60)
  .attr("height",60);


button.on("click", function() {
  mySquare.transition().attr("x",600);
})

</script>
```

I have a square I want to put a transition on. I have button which, when clicked, will have to start the transition. But for some reason it doesnt work. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Why aren't you using it inside an auto-load or jQuery's DOM-ready function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [D3 to select](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) the button element before you can add the onclick functionality to it. Add this line right before `button.on("click", ...)`:

```
var button = d3.select("button");
```

Then you will actually bind the onclick event listener to the button in your page.